# Error during parse String to JSON in slash

Tags: java, json, parsing

I want to transform a String into JSON but the app throw this error:

```
Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)
```

My method:

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplateWCM;

@Value("${app.***.**.*}")
private String root;

@Value("${app.***.**.**.*}")
private String tools;

@Override
public BuscadorWCM getTools() {
String salida = null;
String endpoint = root + tools;
salida = restTemplateWCM.getForObject(endpoint, String.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
BuscadorWCM actualObj = null;
try {
    actualObj = mapper.readValue(salida, BuscadorWCM.class);
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return actualObj;
}
```

The JSON that i try to get is this:

```
"herramientas":[  
      {  
         "uuid":"abc",
         "tituloHerramienta":"abc",
         "tooltipHerramienta":"abc",
         "urlHerramienta":"abc",
         "icono":"abc",
         "textoHerramienta":"abc",
         "manual":{  
            "linkManual":"/abc/def/ghi/file.pdf",
            "textoManual":"abc",
            "iconoManual":"/abc/def/ghi/image.png"
         },
         "ficheros":[  
            {  
               "tituloFichero":"zxc",
               "tipoFichero":"zxc",
               "iconoFichero":"zxc",
               "imagenFichero":"/abc/def/zxc/image.png",
               "docFichero":"zxc",
               "linkFichero":"zxc"
            }
          ]
      }
]
```

My classes:

```
public class BuscadorWCM {

    private List<HerramientaBuscadorWCM> herramientas;
}

public class HerramientaBuscadorWCM {

    private String uuid;
    private String tituloHerramienta;
    private String tooltipHerramienta;
    private String urlHerramienta;
    private String icono;
    private String textoHerramienta;
    private ManualWCM manual;
    private List<FicheroWCM> ficheros;
}
```

ManualWXM class is only three strings and FciheroWCM six strings.

The error said that in line 8 column 11 is the problem in the json ('<' simbol). I can´t transform string with '>' into JSON?

I tried with ResponseEntity but didn't work.
How i can do it?

Comment: Could you provide the code of you BuscadorWCM Pojo?

Comment: Also posting the full method of the controller would be helpful in order to see how the controller is setup and what type that method is returning.

Comment: The JSON you posted is the same you have as content of salida variable?

Comment: Yes, is the same

Comment: why is herramientas array not inside a JSONObject??

Answer (score 1):

I think it just because of you raw JSON is not valid.

I see that a `]` is mission at the end.

If the json is valid. mapper.readValue(salida, BuscadorWCM.class), should marshall the string jSON in the object.

**EDIT 2 :**

I'm pretty sure it because of your field `imagenFichero` in POJO `FicheroWCM`. It is better to keep this field as a File variable

```
public class FicheroWCM {
    // other properties
    private File imagenFichero;
}
```

Jackson would do the mapping automatically detechting the path of the File.

Comment: It would be great if you accept the answer. Glad that helped!